# VueJs: Failed To Mount Component

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue Router and instead of loading the component it throws me this vague error:

```
Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in
---> <Anonymous>
       <Root>
```

**Here is my entry point (app.js)** (note I'm using multiple entries in combination with the CommonsChunksPlugin):

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import '../../../assets/css/main.css'

import App from './app.vue'

new Vue(App).$mount('#app')
```

**The Html File (app.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**(app.vue)**

```
<template>
<div>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    import {
            router,
    } from './bootstrap.js';
    export default {
        router,
    };
</script>
```

**The Router:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

var routes = [
                {
                    path: '/login',
                    name: 'login.index',
                    component: require('./index/index.vue'),
                },
                {
                    path: '/',
                    redirect: '/login',
                },
        ];

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export const router = new VueRouter({
     routes,
});


Vue.router = router;

export default {
    router,
};
```

**And Finally the Component:**

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

I get redirected to /login as expected but the component won't load.

Comment: What version of vue-loader are you using?

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm using vue-loader version 13.0.4.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @JanSchmutz i'm running into the same issue, how did you resolve this please?

Answer (score 23):

You might be running into the breaking change described here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v13.0.0

Try adding .default to the end of your `require()`.

```
component: require('./index/index.vue').default
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately this didn't change it for me, as I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would be it as I was able to reproduce your error with a similar setup. Just to confirm: did you re-run webpack after making the change?

Comment: The '.default' did it for me!

Comment: Excellent this saved me when pulling forward some legacy code

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported your component in app.js file, you should import this component file. Let say it's name is xyz.vue

`import componentName from 'path';`

```html
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```